# How to create Java model with java.awt.image.BufferedImage as parameter using xsd

Tags: java, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I want to create a model which contains the property of type `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`, I tried to create it but getting error as follows

`src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage' to a(n) 'type definition' component.`

My XSD code:=

```
<xsd:complexType name="MyFrame">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="frameNo" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="frame" type="xsd:base64Binary" minOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="bufferedImage" type="java.awt.image.BufferedImage" minOccurs="1" /> //here is the error
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Please show the code or describe the steps you take to cause the error. An XSD file itself doesn't cause an error.

Comment: Of course you got that error.  An XML schema type is not a Java type.  Use `xsd:base64Binary` like the line above is using.  To convert a BufferedImage to bytes, write it to an image format (like PNG), or obtain its Raster and write the DataBuffer (in which case you also need to save the SampleModel somehow).

Comment: You can also implement and configure `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` which would convert between `xsd:base64Binary` and `BufferedImage`.